# accepting XML string in Web method

Tags: c#, xml, webapi

It may be a noob question but it's bugging me alot. i've created a web method as follows.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "SampleWebMethod", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
[OperationContract]
string SampleWebMethod(string xmlParam);
```

The requirement is that it will contain XML string and later i will process the XML. However, when generating the sample request it's generating as follows.

```
<string>String content</string>
```

The requirement is to send request without "string" tag as root. so the request should be like:-

```
<TRANSACTION>
<MESSAGE_HEADER>
<SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID>ABC</SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID>
</MESSAGE_HEADER>
</TRANSACTION>
```

without string as enclosing tags. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found couple of links on SO, please go through them and I'm sure you will find your way through -

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439367/wcf-rest-what-is-it-expecting-my-xml-to-look-like-in-requests)

[one more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253163/passing-xml-string-in-the-body-of-wcf-rest-service-using-webinvoke)

[and the last one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906692/how-to-send-xml-via-post-with-wcf)